# How do I input Chinese text into VBA Editor in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba, cjk

I need to insert Chinese characters into the Properties of VBA editor.

I am using Windows 10 and Excel 2010.

I have just re-installed Simplified Chinese language pack into the Control Panel>Region>Languages (English is main, Chinese is secondary).

I have also installed another Simplified Chinese pack into Office 2010.

Chinese characters show ???? in Properties box in VBA Editor
[image]

In other PCs using Windows 8.1, this is working fine.

I believe [How To Display Foreign Characters In Excel VBE](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html) is for Windows 8.1. Didn't work for Windows 10.

Comment: Not sure if you have see [THIS](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)

Comment: Yes I have.  But I believe that is for Windows 8.1.  Didn't work for Windows 10.